# Remove glossy from my game icon in GameCenter app

Tags: iphone, icons, game-center

How to do it?

`UIPrerenderedIcon` removes glossiness only for springboard icons.

Comment: Good question. I've only used it for springboard type.

Comment: Any screenshots of that?

Comment: BoltClock, you can launch Game Center app and look at "Games" page - some icons are glossed. My app is glossed in spite of prerendered icon flag.

Comment: not everyone has iPhones and/or are running Game Center. Screenshots would be handy. Without knowing what the effect is then my sugestion below may or may not make sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Has your binary been uploaded and approved by Apple?

In my experience, until you upload your binary, iTunes Connect and Game Center don't know that you want gloss to be turned off. They get this info from your app plist after you upload it. After your game goes live, the glossiness should be gone (that's what happened for me, anyways).

Comment: Very likely it's right... I will know exactly when the app will appear in AppStore

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can't. Remember that the icon on App Store is glossy, too. And the "gloss" on Game Center includes shadow, border, and a lot of other effects.

Answer (score 0):

Like previously answered you can't remove the glossiness as that is added automatically by the device it is running on.

Answer (score 0):

Potentially you could design your game icon with a 'inversion' of the gloss effect applied?
That way in Game Center your game icon would appear as normal once the gloss effect is overlaid.

With regards to the SpringBoard, you would turn off the `UIPrerenderedIcon` flag so it would also appear correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do to stop gloss from appearing on your iPhone app icon. (same thing that @Coxy was saying, just in more detail): When you are in Xcode, open the "Resources" folder and open the file "yourAppName-info.plist".  Add a new item to the list of properties and in the "Key" column type in `UIPrerenderedIcon`. Click away and the name will change to "Icon Already Includes Gloss Affects".  In the "Value" column, make sure the box is checked and it should leave the icon with no gloss. I tested it and it works fine on the homescreen icon, and therefor it should work with the GameCenter icon as well.  NOTE: If you leave no icon for the app it stays glossy. There needs to be an icon file for it to show up with no gloss.

Answer (score 0):

Just include a row in the plist file "Icon already includes gloss effects" and check the checkbox. Hope will do this.